# i Want to make individual textbox cell readable based on checkboxColumn in C# datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, checkbox, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fSee.png)

> I wanted to make textbox column single cell readonly to false based on
>   checkbox. if a checkbox is checked then rextbox would be writable.

```html
        private void dgvItem_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        { bool valid = Convert.ToBoolean(this.dgvItem.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); //null reference exception
            if(valid)
            {
                this.dgvItem.CurrentRow.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
```

s checkd then cell would writable. but i get

> null reference exception everytime

Comment: This is a duplicate of: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CurrentRow could be null, or the cell value could be null.
Use the following code

```
private void dgvItem_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if column 0 is the checkbox column, then execute the code only for it
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) 
    {
        bool valid = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToString(this.dgvItem.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value));
        this.dgvItem.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].ReadOnly = !valid;
    }
}
```